# Use XPath in nodeset repeater (XForms)

Tags: html, xml, xpath, xforms, exist-db

I have a question about XPath and the nodeset repeater (XForms).
As you can see in the following code snippet I want to change an attribute of a specific entry of a list and additionally an attribute in the following entry in the nodeset with a trigger.
The first `<xf:action>` works fine but the second does not. What I want here is to leave the current nodeset of the processinstance, go to the following one and change the attribute state here. How do I realize that with XPath?

```
<div>
    <xf:model>
        <xf:instance xmlns="" id="template">
            <project id="">
                <name/>
                ...
                <processinstance>
                    <name>
                    <state>
                </processinstance>
            </project>
        </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>

    ....

    <!-- Process repeat table -->
    <div>
        <table class="table table-hover">
            <thead>
                <th width="50%">Processname</th>
                <th width="50%">State</th>
                <th width="50%">Action</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="process-repeat" xf:repeat-nodeset="//project[index('project-repeat')]/processinstance">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xf:output ref="name"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xf:output ref="state"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xf:group ref=".[state eq 'in processing']">
                            <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                                <xf:label>finish process</xf:label>
                                <xf:action>
                                    <xf:setvalue ref="state">finished</xf:setvalue>
                                </xf:action>

                                <!-- THE FOLLOWING DOES NOT WORK AS I WANT! -->
                                <xf:action>
                                    <xf:setvalue ref="//project[index('project-repeat')]/processinstance[index(process-repeat)+1]">in process</xf:setvalue>
                                </xf:action>
                            </xf:trigger>
                        </xf:group>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Best regards,
Felix

Answer (score 0):

One thing is that you have a typo:

```
index(process-repeat)
```

vs.

```
index('process-repeat')
```

In addition, the `index()` function represents the currently *selected*, in the UI, repeat iteration. It does not represent the *current* iteration being evaluated in XPath.

The bottom line is that you cannot use `index('process-repeat')` to identify the current repeat iteration. It is a common misunderstanding of the `index()` function.

Some implementations have functions to identify the current repeat iteration. I assume you are using BetterFORM, and I don't know if it has such a function. With Orbeon Forms you could write:

```
//project[index('project-repeat')]/processinstance[xxf:repeat-position()]
```

Or better, if betterFORM supports variables, you could use that to avoid repeating yourself with:

```
<tbody id="process-repeat" xf:repeat-nodeset="//project[index('project-repeat')]/processinstance">
    <xf:var name="current-process" value="."/>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xf:output ref="name"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xf:output ref="state"/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xf:group ref=".[state eq 'in processing']">
                <xf:trigger appearance="minimal">
                    <xf:label>finish process</xf:label>
                    <xf:action>
                        <xf:setvalue ref="state">finished</xf:setvalue>
                    </xf:action>
                    <xf:action>
                        <xf:setvalue ref="$current-process">in process</xf:setvalue>
                    </xf:action>
                </xf:trigger>
            </xf:group>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Unfortunately both solutions do not work and yes I use betterFORM. I cannot even jump into another processinstance when I state an exact index like that: `<xf:setvalue ref="//project[index('project-repeat')]/processinstance[2]">in process</xf:setvalue>` But when I use this expression out of that <tbody>-tag it works but that is something I don't want to.

Comment: Sorry about that, but since I don't know betterFORM in details I cannot do much more. Maybe ask the authors directly or via their mailing-list.